# How to empty the main branch repository on GitHub.com

Tags: git, github

I wonder how to empty a repository that's on my main branch on the GitHub.com..
I tried to search google for it but I couldn't find the working method

I don't want to delete the repository, only want to empty it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all Git Commit History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969775/delete-all-git-commit-history)

Comment: Actually, deleting the repo and creating it afresh is a very good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach should work:

```sh
# Initialize a new repository in an empty folder
mkdir newfolder
cd newfolder
git init

# Configure your Github remote repository as "origin"
git remote add origin git@github.com:myprofile/myrepository.git

# Create an initial, empty commit.
git commit --allow-empty -m "Initial empty commit"

# Override the remote git history with the empty commit
git push --force origin master
```